# missing second(00) from LocalDateTime.parse

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

missing second (00) from `LocalDateTime.parse`

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.NOON;
DateTimeFormatter formatTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String value ="20200810" + time.format(formatTime);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss"));
```

LOGS

```
=========value========== 2020081012:00:00
===localDateTime===2020-08-10T**12:00**
```

I tried to change `LocalTime.NOON` to `LocalTime.of(12,0,0)` too but still same result.

Comment: How are you creating the output of "===localDateTime===2020-08-10T12:00"? The issue is there.

Comment: Do you just print `localDateTime` or do you print `localDateTime.format(formatTime)`?

Comment: yes issue after LocalDateTime.parse(). I put system.out.println in code and get logs. System.out.println("===localDateTime===" +localDateTime);

Comment: That's the reason... The default formatter or `toString()` cuts off zero seconds...

Comment: If you just to `System.out.println(localDateTime)` it will call the default implementation of `localDateTime.toString()` which will return `date.toString() + 'T' + time.toString()` and the time.toString() JavaDoc states: "The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero."

Comment: I printed because I was passing LocalDateTime in here. -====== return OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneOffset.UTC);     and this is my final work. it is returning "2020081012:00:Z"  . and i missing 00 second here

Comment: In clear `System.out.println(time)` will not have kept a used format inside. It will print using an ISO format, seemingly stripping 00 seconds. But mind the `T` which is ISO standard for the Time part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the following line into log:

```
localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

The above line returns a string as per [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

You can also specify a custom pattern as per your requirement e.g.

```
localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

or

```
localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss"))
```

If you print `localDateTime` directly, it will print the string returned by `toString` method of `LocalDateTime`.

Note that since the `second` part in the time, `12:00:00` is `00`, the default `toString` implementation of `LocalDateTime` ignores the `second` part.

For your reference, given below is the `toString()` implementation of `LocalDateTime`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return date.toString() + 'T' + time.toString();
}
```

and given below the `toString()` implementation of `LocalTime`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(18);
    int hourValue = hour;
    int minuteValue = minute;
    int secondValue = second;
    int nanoValue = nano;
    buf.append(hourValue < 10 ? "0" : "").append(hourValue)
        .append(minuteValue < 10 ? ":0" : ":").append(minuteValue);
    if (secondValue > 0 || nanoValue > 0) {
        buf.append(secondValue < 10 ? ":0" : ":").append(secondValue);
        if (nanoValue > 0) {
            buf.append('.');
            if (nanoValue % 1000_000 == 0) {
                buf.append(Integer.toString((nanoValue / 1000_000) + 1000).substring(1));
            } else if (nanoValue % 1000 == 0) {
                buf.append(Integer.toString((nanoValue / 1000) + 1000_000).substring(1));
            } else {
                buf.append(Integer.toString((nanoValue) + 1000_000_000).substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

As you can see, the `second` and `nano` parts are included only when their values are greater than `0`.

Comment: Thanks Arvind. Is there a way i can add 00 second after parse?

Comment: @user84 - The recommended way is to get a string formatted by `DateTimeFormatter` as mentioned in my answer. The other way is to override the `toString` implementation of  `LocalDateTime` which I strongly suggest you **NOT** to do.

Comment: @user84 Nothing is missing from your LocalDateTime. It has the exact same value you want and expect it to have. Your issue is with the String representation of said object that you use for log output. If you want the output of your LocalDateTime object to be in a specific format then you need to use a formatter with the format you want for output.

Comment: Thanks All, as per recommend got seconds after again format.